# Does exist any equivalent of the function Cells?

Tags: notebooks

May be I'm wrong but the function `Cells` is absent in *Mathematica* versions prior (at least) 8.0.1. Perhaps what is now natively built in was before implemented as a package.  Please, can you provide any information about that or point to similar code ?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: At present moment I'm using ver. 8.0.1.0

Comment: This looks like a question to WRI.

Comment: It's not a _version_ question. It's, at the root, an _how can I implement..._ one.